# Time series iterated multi-step forecasting autocorrelation issue (propagation of error)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, lags

I am trying to model some (quite ugly) time series data with lagged values of the outcome variable using a non-parametric machine learning model as I do not know how to correctly specify the model. The model training errors (residuals), which are based on one-step ahead forecasts, have very low autocorrelation, which is good. However, when using the model on test data and doing iterated multi-step forecasts (since lagged outcome values are not available) the errors are highly autocorrelated (propagation of error probably). Are there any standard or simple approaches that one could try in such cases to correct iterated multi-step forecasts? The simpler the better.

Rob Hyndman did write about this in https://robjhyndman.com/papers/rectify.pdf, where he tried to correct the multi-step forecasts using his "rectify" method. Does anyone have experience with this and how does it perform in practice?